# Commutative and Cocommutative Quantum Groups

Tags: reference-request, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

I am using this definition:

> An *algebra of functions on a finite quantum group* $\mathbb{G}$ is a finite dimensional $C^\ast$-Hopf algebra $A=:F(\mathbb{G})$.

I have the following (very well known --- folklore --- result)

> *(Classification Theorem)*
>
> Let $A$ be the algebra of functions on a finite quantum group
>   $\mathbb{G}$:
>
> 1. if $A$ is commutative then $\mathbb{G}\cong \Phi(A)$.
> 2. if $A$ is cocommutative then $A=F(\mathbb{G})\cong \mathbb{C} \Phi(A)=:F(\widehat{\Phi(A)})$.

Here $\Phi(A)$ is the set of characters on $A$.

I want to reference these results but am struggling somewhat to find good, old, authoritative references. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you speak of a "finite quantum group", do you mean "a finite dimensional Hopf algebra" ?

Comment: @Konstantinos the definition I am using is in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a quick look into Timmermann's book "An invitation to Quantum Groups".

It refers to:

Saad Baaj; Georges Skandalis
*Unitaires multiplicatifs et dualité pour les produits croisés de C*-algèbres*
Annales scientifiques de l'École Normale Supérieure (1993)
Volume: 26, Issue: 4, page 425-488
ISSN: 0012-9593

They describe finite dimensional C${}^*$-Hopf algebras in terms of multiplicative unitaries.
Theorem 2.2 shows that if you have commutative multiplicative unitaries you get a locally compact group and therefore in the finite case, a finite group.

This gives the first statement. The second statement is equivalent to the first by duality.

*edit*

Such a result is already stated as Theorem 3.3 in

L. I. Vaĭnerman and G. I. Kac, *Nonunimodular Ring Groups and Hopf-Von Neumann algebras*,
Mathematics of the USSR-Sbornik, Volume 23, Number 2

Comment: These sound like ideal references thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I do not work in this area, but take a look at [this survey article](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/ims/bull43/LARS1.ps) in case it gives some directive to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I see on p.18 the article asserts "it is not very hard to see [part 1]" and on p.21 "[part 2] is evident from the duality result below". I could use these but am possibly more interested in an older reference with fuller proofs.

Answer (score 1):

If the definition of a *finite quantum group*, you use, is a pair $(A,\Phi)$ of a finite dimensional $C^*$-algebra $A$, with a comultiplication $\Phi$, such that $(A,\Phi)$ is a Hopf $*$-algebra, then this [paper](http://www.impan.pl/~pmh/teach/intro3/fonsann.pdf) may be helpful.

.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I see on p.16 the paper asserts that "we have the property that a finite quantum group is a group if and only if the underlying algebra $A$ is abelian". I could use this but am possibly more interested in an older reference with fuller proofs. I see no reference to part 2. of my question.